# Functional non recursive approach to looping in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I use Haskell for my programming during leisure these days. Being a programmer in imperative languages for over 8 years, it is tough to wrap my head around some functional constructs (especially the folds). I was solving a problem from project Euler, and happened to produce the following code.

```
f (num, den) s | num*10 < den = s
               | otherwise = f (ratio (num, den) s') s'
               where s' = (s+2)
```

Can this explicit recursion be rewritten using folds or some other functional construct? The main hurdle for me in using a fold was to come up with the step function. Eventually I gave up, and resorted to the recursion.

EDIT: Also, how do I make the output returned by another function within a function as the input to the calling function without explicit recursion?

Comment: This looks like [`until`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:until) to me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's always good old [`until`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:until)

```
f = until test func
  where test ((a, b), _) = a * 10 < b
        func (p, s) = (ratio p s+2, s+2)
```

To be fair though, you're really always going to have some kind of recursion, it's just a matter of how much you abstract it away. There is no "loop" in Haskell.

As to your second question, I believe you've just asked "How do I have a function call itself without doing recursion". In short, you can't since that's the definition of recursion.

However with higher order functions like `until` `iterate` and `fix` (Look at the implementation of that one) you can avoid ever having to call your worker function. They take care of doing the explicit recursion under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to until. As for the 2nd part, what I meant was whether explicit recursion can be avoided, by using the higher order constructs as you have described. The 'until', 'iterate' and 'fix' were all unknown to me as of now. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: No worries! Haskell's prelude is very expansive and powerful and has lots of nooks and crannies filled with useful functions like that

Comment: If I've answered your question, feel free to click the check box beside my answer to mark your question as "answered".

Comment: probably worth mentioning foldr and map etc. as well